# ios Passcode field - needing to set it up in settings bundle

Tags: ios, passwords, keychain

I have got a passcode all up and running (4 digit login) and i need to get the option working so that the end user can assign their passcode in the settings.bundle.

At the moment, which I know is not ideal, I have a simple PSTextFieldSpecifier where the user can type in 4 numbers and login with those.

For reasons of security and having no control of what is typed into that field it will not do.

**Where do I need to look to set up the screen for the passcode to be set up?**

Cheers jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings bundle should be used only in a limited set of use-cases (as users often don't change individual app settings for months at a time, or not at all), and as such, limited control is given to developers as to the settings bundle and it's default controls.  You'll need to use some kind of in-app settings, which are very easy to implement, and allow easier and faster access to something as variable as a username-password association.  [CocoaControls](http://cocoacontrols.com/) hosts a wide variety of simple frameworks and templates for in-app settings.  I recommend you start your search there.

Comment: Thanks - I was not aware of that website. I'll check it out:-)